# Как добавить обработку медиафайлов на aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Есть код, который исправно обеспечивает связь между админами и юзером

```
async def handle_admin_response(message: types.Message):
    if message.reply_to_message:
        match = re.search(r'\((\d+)\)', message.reply_to_message.text)

        if match:
            extracted_number = match.group(1)
            reply_for_user = f'{message.text}'
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=extracted_number, text=reply_for_user)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Нет ответа на сообщение.")


@dp.message_handler(lambda message: user_data.get(message.from_user.id, {}).get('chatting'))
async def handle_user_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username

    for admin_id in ADMINS_ID:
        forward_message_text = f"Пользователь @{username} ({chat_id}) отправил сообщение:\n\n {message.text}"
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=admin_id, text=forward_message_text)
```

Выполнен на aiogram. Проблема в том, что хотелось бы встроить в него ответы с медиафайлами, так как сейчас бот просто на них не реагирует. Может помочь кто с этим?

Comment: И в чем проблема? Добавьте хендлеры для медиафайлов или расширьте существующий, добавив обработку нужных типов

Comment: А как добавить эти хендлеры, подскажите?
С aiogram'ом мало работал, как правильно будет их выполнить? Или код расширить?

Answer (score 0):

Можешь сделать так, как документации написанно [MagicFilters](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters/magic_filters.html):

```
@dp.message(F.photo or F.video)
    async def f(msg: Message):
```